# I want to automate nslookup process from using a Batch file. Want to pass the address from a JAVA program.

Tags: java, batch-file, batch-processing

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
if exist hostnames.txt del hostnames.txt
for /F %%A in (%1) do nslookup %%A >> solution.txt
```

Tried using this program but it ain't running. Don't know why.

Comment: and what happens? What argument is passed to the script?

Comment: Hey, npocmaka, I think there was error with the directories and it worked. Thanks for the help.